# how to control the find() to get all children with parent comment

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am a bigenner in mongoose, I implement a concept of comment. In fact, I create a schema comment in which I identify the different fields, as it is shown:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
/* eslint-disable-next-line */
import db from './db';

// Define Schema method= mongoose;
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  author_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
  },
  creation_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  interesting_comment: [String],
  updated_content_list: [{ previous_date: Date, previous_content: String }],
  children: [String],
});
export default mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Note: children is about the response to a parent comment, here is the example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60217951f57f24079f885d66"),
    "interesting_comment" : [
        "6ff10e9"
    ],
    "children" : [
        "c13e5487-07ba-4bc9-996e-ef1c8f826b32"
    ],
    "updated_content_list" : [ ],
    "id" : "6f169ee4-d22d-49a2-9f71-5dacadecf6bb",
    "author_id" : "b08a3310-b3f4-4521-9b1a-2d5667a3ea1d",
    "content" : "Hello wijdene",
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2021-02-08T17:48:01.026Z"),
    "__v" : 4
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("602179d1f57f24079f885d68"),
    "interesting_comment" : [ ],
    "children" : [ ],
    "updated_content_list" : [ ],
    "id" : "c13e5487-07ba-4bc9-996e-ef1c8f826b32",
    "author_id" : "111",
    "content" : "hi nesrine",
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2021-02-08T17:50:09.075Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I implement this function:

```
async function ListComment() {
  const comments = await Comment.find();
  return comments;
}
```

I want to get all the children by their parent comment, I spend hours and I don't get the idea any help please

Comment: Have you tried [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#graphlookup-aggregation)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try with it, I have no idea about it

Comment: async function ListComment() {
  const comments = await Comment.aggregate([{$unwind:{path:"$children",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},{$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"children",foreignField:"id",as:"children"}}]);
  return comments;
} I try by this way but I want to remove the child

Answer (score 0):

I try to fix this problem with lookup:

```
async function ListComment() {
  const comments = await Comment.aggregate([{$unwind:{path:"$children",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},{$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"children",foreignField:"id",as:"children"}}]);
  return comments;
}
```

But even the child, it is shown in this way. In fact, I add preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true to preserve parent which doesn't contain a child. But what I get is the new combination + parent without children+children. I want to remove children, any idea